# How to specify the the column width but also keep the cell content center horizontally?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

I want to specify the width of the column but also keep the content centered. How can I do that?

Here is my code

---

```
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm} c c p{2cm} p{3cm}}

\Xhline{3\arrayrulewidth}\hline

Location& Tailings& Years& Dominant metal or mineral& Source\\

\midrule

Freda-Redridge, Keweenaw Peninsula, Michigan, U.S.A.& 39.2 Tg& 1901-1947& Copper& Kerfoot et al. 2009\\

Gay, Keweenaw Peninsula, Michigan, U.S.A.& 22.5 Tg& 1901-1932& Copper& Kerfoot et al. 2009\\

Silver Bay, Minnesota, U.S.A.& 500 Tg& 1955-1980& Iron& Cook et al. 1974\\

Rupert Inlet, British Columbia, Canada& 353 Tg& 1971-1995& Copper& Burd 2002\\

Britannia Beach, Howe Sound, north of Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada& 44 Tg& 1904-1974& Copper, zinc& Chretien 1997\\

Ensenada Chapaco Bay, north-central Chile& 2,612,103 kg d$^{-1}$& 1978-1994& Iron tailings (pelletization)& Lancellotti and Stotz 2004\\

Chanaral Bay, Atacama Region, Chile& 150 Tg& 1938-1974& Copper, arsenic& Castilla and Nealler 1978; Andrade et al. 2006\\

Qaumaujuk and Agfardlikavsa Fjords, Greenland& 11.8 Tg& 1973-1990& Lead, zinc, silver& Asmund et al. 1994\\

Rize, Black Sea, Turkey& 2,880,103 kg d$^{-1}$& 1994-2000& Copper, arsenic, lead& Berkun 2005\\

Chameis Bay, Namibia, Africa& 366 Tg& 1970-2006& Diamonds& Smith 2006\\

Elizabeth Bay, Namibia, Africa& 7 Tg& 1991-1998& Diamonds& Smith et al. 2002\\

Calancan Bay, Marinduque Island, Luzon, Philippines& 200 Tg& 1975-1991& Copper& Marges et al. 2011\\

Buyat Bay, North Sulawesi, Indonesia& 1,841,103 kg d$^{-1}$& 1996-present& Gold& Edinger et al. 2008\\

Toga, Melanesia, Western Pacific& 2.5 Tg yr21& 1990s& Phosphate; Cd, Pb, Cu in tailings& Gnandi\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\label{T5C3}

\end{table}

\end{spacing}

\end{landscape}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I marked your code as a [code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: We will close this question as a duplicate, though of course your question is ok. It can be reopened if you would decide to edit it to make clear that it's somehow different to the linked duplicates.